# How to display GuestToCustomer in customer grid in custom column?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento2.2, magento2.4

I have extension installed in my project which converts **guest customer** to **customer**,
and i want to display this customer is "**Guest to Customer**" in my custom column in customer grid,
[image]
Something like that in this picture.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which extension you have used for guest to customer?

Comment: GuestToCustomer extension of BSS Commerce Co.

https://bsscommerce.com/magento-2-guest-to-customer-extension.html#:~:text=Guest%20to%20Customer%20is%20an,order%2Dsaving%20function%20of%20emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Register column with custom column class**

`app/code/Acme/StackExchange/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="convert_to_customer" class="Acme\StackExchange\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\ConvertToCustomer" sortOrder="90">
            <settings>
                <label translate="true">Convert to Customer</label>
                <bodyTmpl>ui/grid/cells/html</bodyTmpl>
                <filter>false</filter>
                <sortable>false</sortable>
            </settings>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

**2. Create Column processor**

`app/code/Acme/StackExchange/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/ConvertToCustomer.php`

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Acme\StackExchange\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;

class ConvertToCustomer extends Column
{
    protected UrlInterface $urlBuilder;

    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;

        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource): array
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$item) {
                $content = '&nbsp;';
                if (empty($item['customer_id'])) {
                    $url     = $this->urlBuilder->getUrl('path/to/url', [
                        'order_id' => $item['entity_id'],
                    ]);
                    $title   = __('Guest To Customer');
                    $content = <<<HTML
<a target="_blank" class="product_link" href="{$url}">{$title}</a>
HTML;
                }
                $item[$this->getName()] = $content;
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

Comment: i have another question posted kindly can you answer?

Comment: Feel free to ask

Comment: Here is my question link, can you take a look?

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/357972/magento2-4-how-to-add-custom-sort-options-in-backend-and-sort-product-on-storef/357974#357974